# Does C# have an internal contant for the C++ MAX_PATH value?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

In C++ MAX_PATH is defined as 260.  Is there a constant in C# defined somewhere that serves the same purpose?

Comment: I copy/pasted your title into google: https://www.google.com/search?q=Does+C%23+have+an+internal+contant+for+the+C%2B%2B+MAX_PATH+value%3F&sxsrf=AJOqlzW-VCPAejAdzBs-89s-rgWbEeGcxw%3A1676668855710&source=hp&ei=t-_vY7qRKPjP0PEPsKAl&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY-_9x-Wi5YAXjVhzz8qMvVoM_1s6Uk1P&ved=0ahUKEwj6yLCcvp39AhX4JzQIHTBQCQAQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=Does+C%23+have+an+internal+contant+for+the+C%2B%2B+MAX_PATH+value%3F&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwghEKABEAoyBwghEKABEAoyBwghEKABEAo6BwgjEOoCECdQ1k9Y1k9g41xoAnAAeACAAYQBiAGEAZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAqABAbABCg&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: In C++, MAX_PATH will vary by platform.  Some platforms (like Windows), MAX_PATH is only relevant for a specific API subset.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-existing `MAX_PATH` constant defined in C#.  You will have to declare you own constant in your own code, eg:

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/MAX_PATH.html

```cs
const int MAX_PATH = 260;
```